# Does NetLogo honor patch sizes less than 1.0?

Tags: netlogo

Changing the patch size to a value less than 1.0 in the Model Settings dialog and then saving and reopening the model leaves the graphics window the same size.

The patch size value is still reported correctly in Model Settings.

Am I missing something?

Attached are screenshots of this problem. I have not run `setup` or any other routine, I just opened the model. My code does not contain `set-patch-size`.

Shown are patch sizes of 1.0, 0.5, and 0.25, which all produce identical graphics windows (in black). A screenshot of patch size of 1.5 is also included to illustrate that NetLogo honors this value and resizes the graphics window accordingly (note the scroll bars).

Any help is appreciated!

[Patch size 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y0xq.png)

[Patch size 0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x8js.png)

[Patch size 0.25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KPdf.png)

[Patch size 1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L20U1.png)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

I was later able to replicate the user's original behavior in both 6.0.2 and 6.0.4.

Which version of NetLogo are you using? The patch size view preserved for me in 6.0.2:

Opened after saving with patch size 1:

[image]

Opened after saving with patch size 0.5:

[image]

However, this may not really matter, other than for viewing purposes. Is the worry that your distance values will be off? Patch size is really just for viewing purposes and doesn't really have anything to do with model function- for example `fd 1` will always move the turtle forward the width of one patch, regardless of patch size.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's NetLogo 6.0.4. My concern is only for model demonstration—I understand that it won't affect any calculations.

Comment: @user10709233 - I just tried with 6.0.4, and found the same issue you had, then played around in 6.0.2 some more and was able to replicate it there in some cases as well. Seems like you're right- the display will default to some minimum patch size display, even when the patch size is set to lower than 1. I guess you could use the `startup` primitive to enforce a patch-size on model start, something like `to startup set-patch-size 0.5 end`. Sorry to not be more help!